# PagingAndSortingRepository first page loads very slow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using **PagingAndSortingRepository** for pagination.
With a few data everything works fine.

When I have larger datasets with over about 1000 entries, I have performance issues while loading the **first** page.
All other pages are loaded a lot faster (Order of requests doesn't have any impact on performance).

My Repository looks like this:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyObject, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyObject> {
}
```

I'm calling it this way:

```java
Specifications<MyObject> filter= getMyFilter();
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);
Page<MyObject> page = this.myRepository.findAll(filter, pageable);
```

My first assumption was that for page 1 some expensive SQL queries are generated. But there was no big difference between the statements for page 1 and page 2.
Also, they are both doing a count. First, I thought this could be the reason.

I guess the problem is within the repository.
Did anybody have the same issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem were some statistics in the mssql database.
After i deleted them the performance issues was solved.

Comment: Can you please share what statistics were causing the problem?

Comment: "The Query Optimizer uses statistics to create query plans that improve query performance." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver16.